# Вывод индекса полученного целочисленного значения в массиве Java

Tags: java, массивы, индексы

Сам только начинаю писать на Java, просьба не пинать. Простая задачка, имеется толпа учеников, им ставят оценки (я вывожу случайные от 1 до 90). Необходимо найти наивысшую оценку, но на печать вывести её номер, а не значение. С первой частью справился, оценку нашёл, как найти её номер (индекс)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int marks[] = new int[5]; //массив, количество учеников
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        marks[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 90 + 1); //присваивание оценок
    }
    int maxMark = marks[0]; // присваивание максимального значения оценки
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) { //цикл поиска максимального значения
        if (maxMark < marks[i])
            maxMark = marks[i];
    }
    System.out.println(maxMark); //Вывод максимальной оценки
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int marks[] = new int[5]; //массив, количество учеников
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            marks[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 90 + 1); //присваивание оценок
        }
        int maxMarkIndex = 0;
        int maxMark = marks[0]; // присваивание максимального значения оценки
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) { //цикл поиска максимального значения
            if (maxMark < marks[i]){
                maxMark = marks[i];
                maxMarkIndex = i;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(maxMark); //Вывод максимальной оценки
        System.out.println(maxMarkIndex); //Вывод индекса максимальной оценки
    }
}
```

Или же вас интересует конкретный метод для нахождения индекса по значению?
`marks.indexOf(maxMark)` (Если честно, не уверен, что это работает с массивом int)

Comment: indexOf  - не  работает для простых объектов, кажется... Он будет присваивать значение "-1".  Но указанное Вами решение то что мне нужно.

Comment: Тогда было бы здорово, если бы вы поставили галочку, если мой ответ решил вашу проблему :)

Comment: поставил. Спасибо